# Magento show a products promotion under the product name on the product listing page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, ce-1.9.0.1

I have seen this feature on several websites, and included in a few expensive extensions, however I am wondering if its as simple as a few code changes on catalog/product/list.phtml. Any help is appreciated.

Example under each product that is included in said promotion

> On The Byas Axer Henley Crew T-Shirt
>
> $19.99
>
> **Buy one Get one Free**

Comment: what kind of product you want to show?
Is it a common product from a category or special product with special category?

Comment: Not really sure what your asking. The products I use are simple and configurable. No special categories.